# MSMQ: Moving client from WIndows XP to Windows 7, issue in ping

Tags: .net, windows, msmq

We have an issue moving a .NET client app from Windows XP to Windows 7, connected to a WIndows 2003 server.
The client loose connection to the server, and this seems to be something related to changes in underlying ping system.
It seems the server side MSMQ (3.X) which is on Windows 2003 is expecting a ping that is not anymore provided by the Windows 7 client (MSMQ 4.X)
Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\Security\EnablePingService to 1.

[Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2010/03/05/port-3527.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Create the program and compile it then on the windows 7 os you want to run the program navigate to the folder that your programs .exe is located and then right click on the .exe and choose properties and go into compatiblity choose windows xp.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it doesn't fix the issue... the problem is linked to the MSMQ version

Comment: Try to change the target .net framework to a lower version it is worth a shot. You can read this little article if it has any information on your problem: http://tech.alirazazaidi.com/what-is-msmq-and-how-to-configure-it-on-windows-7/