# Deploying MS queuing app to Windows 7

Tags: windows, queuing

It seems the queuing from Microsoft is not working properly on Windows 7. The pinging is not working. The same app works on Windows XP.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Hi this could help you maybe...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251484/msmq-moving-client-from-windows-xp-to-windows-7-issue-in-ping